# MS SQL doesn't return data in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server

I created config file for database like below:

```
module.exports.connection = {
  sqlserver: {
    user: 'user_name',
    password: 'password',
    server: 'servername\\instancename',
    database: 'database_name',
    port: 1433,
  },
};
```

I have a simple table in database:

[image]

I'm trying get a data from table above like below:

```
const sql = require('mssql');
const config = require('../config/connection');

sql.connect(config.connection.sqlserver).then((pool) => pool.request().query('select type from dbo.category')).then((result) => {
  console.log(result);
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
});

sql.close();
```

Unfortunately I doesn't see anything in console and I don't have any error so I can't find what's wrong. 
I tried also:

```
sql.connect(config.connection.sqlserver).then((pool) => pool.request().query('select type from dbo.category')).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  }).then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
  sql.close();
```

I used https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#promises. I'm trying to do it on my nodeJs server. Any ideas?

Comment: try change your query like this `select * from category`and check what it returns, and also add some string to console log to see if then or catch worked. Like this 'console.log('then() handled. Result: ', result);'

Comment: I tried and nothing. Any errors.

Comment: ok, are you checked that this code was called? Add console before and after this code, and also you can try test only connection first

`sql.connect(config.connection.sqlserver).then( result => console.log('connected!')).catch((err) => console.log('some error'));`

Comment: Ok so I tried and it works in one situation - when I don't have sql.close(). For example. I'm starting my server and I see "connected" and I have data from my table in result array. But when I do refresh I have an error "Global connection already exists. Call sql.close() first.". I added sql.close() and I don't see anything - even "connected" so still something is wrong.

Comment: oh, yeah. It happens b/c `sql.close()` calling before you finish your query. Just place it into last `then`, and also into catch (to close connection if error). To close it after you'll done. Or use async/await instead of then/catch.

Comment: Everything works. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my problem. Thanks for Julia Shestakova suggestions. 
My query function looks like this:

```
const sql = require('mssql');
const config = require('./config/connection');
module.exports = {
  query(query) {
    return sql.connect(config.connection.sqlserver).then(() => sql.query(query)).then((result) => {
      sql.close();
      return result.recordset;
    }).catch((err) => console.log(err));
  },
};
```

I'm returning Promise so I can use `then` to presentation my data when I'm calling query function on a server.